# Get the follower list of several screen names Twitter R

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I am trying to get the list of followers of each Screen Name as data frame:

```
library(twitteR)
#install.packages("twitteR")
library(httr)
library(SchedulerR

screen = c(1:800)
x=lookupUsers(screen)
SNATWITTER = function(i){for i in screen:a=x$i$getFollowers(),retun(a),i+1}
```

I am getting:

> Error: unexpected '}' in "    }"

Comment: You have unbalanced parenthesis, mis-used for loop syntax and misspelled `return` function.

Comment: In addition to the things listed above, I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Why are you trying to define a function in that way? Can you explain more about what you're trying to do? What is the output you'd like to have? If you don't know, what are you trying to do with the data? A more well formulated **specific** question will get  you a better, more insightful answer.